# MySQL Query: How can I select rows which more times recommended then not recommended

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table:** tbl_1

**Columns:** name, option

```
-> name   |  option
-> abc_1  |  yes
-> abc_2  |  no
-> abc_3  |  yes
-> abc_1  |  no
-> abc_2  |  yes
-> abc_3  |  no
-> abc_1  |  yes
-> abc_2  |  no
-> abc_3  |  yes
-> abc_1  |  yes
-> abc_2  |  no
-> abc_3  |  yes
```

Now, The query I want to ask that ......

How can I get those unique names which are have options:yes more than no ?

The query should return

```
-> name
-> abc_1
-> abc_3
```

I tried lots of queries but did not succeed, Kindly help

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql evaluates Boolean expressions as `0` or `1` for `False` and `True`, so there is no need for `IF` or `CASE` statements:

```
select name
from tbl_1
group by name
having sum(`option` = 'yes') > sum(`option` = 'no')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2bYqfaaaqpbMLkaxZCjiDc/0).
Results:

```
| name  |
| ----- |
| abc_1 |
| abc_3 |
```

Comment: Bro, Thanks for that but it is not returning the result that have only 1 row means having no option value but just 1 record, then this is not returning me that record.

Comment: The query is based on your sample data. What do you mean: *is not returning the result that have only 1 row means having no option value but just 1 record*? Post sample data for this case.

Comment: I means having condition should be something like: having ( (sum(`opinion` = 'yes') > sum(`opinion` = 'no')) OR (sum(`opinion` = 'no')  == 0) )

Comment: Sample data: i have only 1 record for abc_4 which has opinion value == yes then this query will not return that record

Comment: Yest it does return that row. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2bYqfaaaqpbMLkaxZCjiDc/2

Comment: When there is only 1 row with `option` = 'yes' and no row with `option` = 'no' for a name, then `sum(`option` = 'yes') = 1` and `sum(`option` = 'no')=0` so the condition in the HAVING clause is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

A terse MySQL query to return the specfied result would be something like:

```
 SELECT t.name
   FROM tbl_1 t
  GROUP
     BY t.name
 HAVING SUM(IF(t.option = 'yes',1,0)) > SUM(IF(t.option = 'no',1,0))
```

This is using some "conditional aggregation" shorthand.

---

Let's unpack that a bit, so we can get an understanding of what this query is doing. Consider this query:

```
 SELECT t.name
      , t.option
      , IF(t.option = 'yes',1,0) AS option_yes
      , IF(t.option = 'no' ,1,0) AS option_no
   FROM tbl_1 t
  ORDER
     BY t.name
```

The expressions in the SELECT list are evaluated for each row, the IF() function evaluates to either a 1 or a 0.

And now consider what happens when do aggregation of those expressions, adding up all of the 1s and 0s

```
 SELECT t.name
      , t.option
      , SUM( IF(t.option = 'yes',1,0) ) AS cnt_option_yes
      , SUM( IF(t.option = 'no' ,1,0) ) AS cnt_option_no
   FROM tbl_1 t
  GROUP
     BY t.name
      , t.option
```

Now leave "option" out of the group by clause, and do a comparison of the two aggregates.

```
 SELECT t.name
      , SUM( IF(t.option = 'yes',1,0) ) AS cnt_option_yes
      , SUM( IF(t.option = 'no' ,1,0) ) AS cnt_option_no
      , SUM(IF(t.option='yes',1,0) ) > SUM(IF(t.option='no',1,0)) AS _compare
   FROM tbl_1 t
  GROUP
     BY t.name
```

It's possible to do a comparison of the aggregates in a `HAVING` clause. And that yields the query at the very beginning of this answer.

Comment: Query provided in this answer satisfies the specification, for MySQL.  SQL Fiddle demonstration provided here:   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f1e26/1    (And just noting "Error" is practically useless in terms of diagnosing the actual problem.)

Comment: This answer provides an outline of an approach, using conditional aggregation to "count" the number of rows that have a 'yes' and the number of rows that have a 'no' and comparing the counts. The comparison of the aggregates can be done in a HAVING clause, so that only the rows that satisfy the condition are returned. The query provided in this answer is tested against MySQL; a SQL Fiddle demonstration is provided in a previous comment. This same pattern can be used in a variety of RDBMS other than MySQL, the MySQL `IF()` function can be replaced with a more ANSI standard `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation -

```
   select
name,
count (case when `option` = 'yes' then 1 else null end) as y,
count (case when `option` <> 'yes' then 1 else null end) as n
from
tbl_1
group by
`name`
having count (case when `option` = 'yes' then 1 else null end) > count (case when `option` <> 'yes' then 1 else null end)
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3VpKG77L9buHMbCWKhqWAe/0)

Comment: Was missing a single quote.  Working in the linked fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a conditional sum

```
select  name
    , sum( case when `option` ='yes' then 1 else 0 end) num_yes 
    , sum( case when `option` ='no' then  1 else 0 end) num_no 
from my_table  
group by  name  
order by num_yes desc, num_no desc
```

Comment: @J.Doe  answer  updated ..  missing 1 ...anyway show me the exact error message